# Error in colmn vector multiplication ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply a 5x1 matrix with 1x1 matrix in the following way. Every time it is giving the following error

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?)
```

Here is way I am trying with. Please help me to debug the specific instance here

```
>>> m = np.ones(5)
>>> x = np.ones(1)
>>> m.shape
(5,)
>>> x.shape
(1,)
>>> m@x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 5)
>>> m.transpose()@x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `m` is not in 5 x 1 shape. It goes like row by columns.

The number of columns of left operand should match number of rows of right operand. Thus when you do `m @ x`, it is invalid according to matrix multiplication rules.

So do like this:

```
>>> m.reshape(-1, 1) @ x
```

It makes the row vector `m` serve as column vector having shape (5, 1). Also x has one row thus a valid matrix multiplication.

Comment: It's not (1,5), it's (5,)!

Comment: @hpaulj whats the difference? Isn't it a row vector?

Comment: There's no such thing as "row vector" in `numpy`.  Search the docs if you doubt me :)

Comment: @hpaulj When it does matrix multiplication, i think it does see that as (1, 5).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 1d arrays, as printed the shapes are (5,) and (1,).  Those aren't `column vectors` or `row vectors`.

`matmul` docs' description of how it handles 1d arrays can be a bit confusing.  I like `np.dot` docs better.  It treats two 1d arrays as vector dot/inner product.  In either case, both arrays to have a matching size.

Some valid shape combinations:

```
In [90]: np.ones((5,1))@np.ones((1,1))                                                  
Out[90]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
In [91]: _.shape                                                                        
Out[91]: (5, 1)

In [92]: np.ones((5,1))@np.ones((1))                                                    
Out[92]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
In [93]: _.shape                                                                        
Out[93]: (5,)

In [95]: np.ones((1,5))@np.ones((5))                                                    
Out[95]: array([5.])
In [96]: _.shape                                                                        
Out[96]: (1,)

In [97]: np.ones((1,5))@np.ones((5,1))                                                  
Out[97]: array([[5.]])
In [98]: _.shape                                                                        
Out[98]: (1, 1)
```

With 2d (and higher) arrays, the last dim of A must match the 2nd to the last of B.  That's the classic manual scan across the rows and down the columns rule.